# Switching to pages dynamically in Inno Setup

Tags: inno-setup, pascal

I have a requirement to switch to pages dynamically in the Inno setup. Lemme just explain what needs to be done and what I tried so far.

Here is a sample logic mentioned below:

**Page1 --> Page2 --> Page3 --> Page4 --> Page5**

I will get a single value from a series of radio button from **Page3** from the User at runtime and based on that value I need to switch to different pages for **Page4** and **Page5**.

Here is what I tried... :

a.) I wrote all the logic in the `InitializeWizard()` but I could not create **Page4** and **Page5** since it was created based on the value selected from **Page3** and during initialization it is empty.

b.) I tried to write all the logic in the `CurPageChanged(CurPageID: Integer)` procedure, and same thing happened and I could not get the `Page.ID` for any pages in `NextButtonClick(CurPageID: Integer)` (including **Page1** and **Page2**).

Please help me how can I proceed in this situation.

Thanks in Advance,

DeeJay

Comment: `ShouldSkipPage` is the event you're missing. There's gazillion ways how to write your script. One of them you can [`find here`](http://pastebin.com/Zq6XLaad).

Comment: Thanks a lot, I have nt completed, but this shud do the trick...